# Django QR code generation PIL image saving using S3 not working

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-models, django-1.8

I am trying to generate QR code based on model. I am hosting the app at Heroku and using AWS S3 as sotrage. Storage with S3 works totally fine with other model elements, just the model for QR code generation is giving trouble. I am using this link as reference:
https://gilang.chandrasa.com/blog/generate-qr-code-in-django-model/
My model is:

```
class BusinessQRCode(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, null=True)
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    qrcode = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/{}'.format(time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")), blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self):
        super(BusinessQRCode, self).save()
        self.generate_qrcode()

    def generate_qrcode(self):
        from activation.models import RandomFileName

        qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=1,
            error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
            box_size=10,
            border=4,
        )
        qr.add_data('Some data')
        qr.make(fit=True)

        filename = 'qrcode-%s.png' % self.id

        img = qr.make_image()

        from django.conf import settings
        img.save(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + filename)

        # reopen = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + filename, "rb")
        # django_file = File(reopen)
        self.qrcode.save(filename,img, save=True)
```

The above code gives me this error:

```
TypeError

TypeError: seek() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I have tried using the commented code as well, that is opening the file and than trying to save it, but it doesnt work, it just never stops loading. What I mean is this part of the code in the end:

```
reopen = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + filename, "rb")
django_file = File(reopen)
self.qrcode.save(filename,django_file, save=True)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add the traceback for the error. When saving a file to the S3 backend you should use a django `File` object, as in the last example. What type is `img`? The S3 backend doesn't read files directly from your local drive.

Comment: @HåkenLid img is of PIL Pillows image type. I will put the stack trace.

Comment: ImageField.save expects a django File object, so I guess that's why it fails when you pass a PIL.Image. In the default local storage, I think you might get away with passing a pathname as string, but the S3 backend is more strict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have tried using the commented code as well, that is opening the
>   file and than trying to save it, but it doesnt work, it just never
>   stops loading.

I think the last approach should work, but since you use `save=True` when saving the ImageField, that will trigger the parent model's `save()` method as well. So you will end up in an infinite loop.

Change the order you save the imagefield and the model.

```
def save(self):
    # Generate qrcode before calling super.save
    self.generate_qrcode() 
    super(BusinessQRCode, self).save()

def generate_qrcode(self):

    ...

    with open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + filename, "rb") as reopen:
        django_file = File(reopen)
        self.qrcode.save(filename,django_file, save=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works :) I will put the solution as well.

Comment: In most cases this kind of infinite recursion would quickly hit python's recursion limit and you would see a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.` However, since you are sending the file to S3 over the internet every time you save, you will have to wait quite a while before hitting the recursion limit. If you have a bug like this in production, you will at least notice it when you get your monthly bill from Amazon.